# How to split the text in css

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my Java script code which i use to append

```
   cvg.append('<text  x="20" y="1034" style="font-size: 14px;font-style:   italic;">' + Note + '</text>');
```

The data which the "Note" displaying is a Json value, which is very large and is not getting displayedproperly.Only a portion of it is getting displayed.Please help me to split the text in to two line so that they get display properly..?

Comment: if it's json you should stringify by `JSON.stringify(Note)` if you put it with text in the append

Comment: What are the input data? What is the current result? What is the desired result?

Comment: This the actual input: Numbers presented herein are the result of a data harmonization effort, which enables cross-country comparability. They may therefore differ from the values of each country's national statistics agency. And the current result is:-  Numbers presented herein are the result of a data harmonization effort, which enables cross-country comparability. They may therefore differ from the values of ea.

Comment: @adidi.. its not the issue with the json string.The data is getting properly but the display part is going out.So the rest of data is not showing..